# Can not build Gradle project with Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, tostring, build.gradle

I'm using Android Studio 0.3.0 (configured to use gradle wrapper to build), Gradle 1.8. Everytime I build (or rebuild) the project with Android Studio, I get the error:

```
Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':MyProject'.
> For input string: ""
```

Clicking on the error, here is the error code in build.gradle:

```
def getCommitsCount() {
    return 'git rev-list --count HEAD'.execute().text.toInteger()
}
```

If I remove `.toInteger()` then the error is gone. Otherwise, I can build the project from console just fine `./gradlew clean check build`.

Anyone is getting the same problem? It seems to be a problem of Android Studio. If you know any workaround or fix, that would be cool.

Comment: For an unknown reason, calling `'git rev-list --count HEAD'.execute().text` from Android Studio always return `""`. So I made a workaround by checking if text is an integer before casting it to integer: `return result.isInteger() ? result.toInteger() : 0`

Answer (score 3):

To find out what is the reason that output stream is empty access the error stream using `err`.

```
def getCommitsCountError() {
    return 'git rev-list --count HEAD'.execute().err.text.toInteger()
}
```

Is likely as JChord pointed that error can be.

> "xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun"

Then the solution is to (re)install Xcode Command Line Tools.

`xcode-select --install`

as [git is connected to it.](http://tips.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/10/01/xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path-library-developer-commandline-tools-missing-xcrun/)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you've removed the xcode causes the issuse. Try to reinstall Command Line Tools to make sure the git work normal.

run as below command:

`xcode-select --install`

Click “Install” to download and install Xcode Command Line Tools.

Answer (score 0):

I think Android Studio run "make" from a different directory, so here is my fix and it works as expected:

```
def getCommitsCount() {
    return "git --git-dir=${projectDir}/.git --work-tree=${projectDir} rev-list --count HEAD".execute().text.toInteger()
}
```

Comment: I found this to be the issue in my case although it only worked with ${rootDir} since the ${projectDir} would be ${rootDir}/app and my repo is stored under the root.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with getting the commit count. What worked for me finally was

```
def getGitCommitCount() {
   def process = "git rev-list HEAD --first-parent --count".execute()
   return process.text.toInteger()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I didn't have a Xcode version selected.

You can also try reinstalling Xcode Command Line Tools: `xcode-select --install`